# Changing screen resolution in CentOS

Tags: centos, resolution

I'm trying to change my screen resolution to 1920x1200 with no luck. I actually did successfully change it, but once I log in it changes back to 800x600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has worked for me.  Try running this on the command line:

First, make a backup of the config file:

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/x11/backup.xorg.conf
```

Then configure the display to the resolution you want:

```
system-config-display --reconfig --set-resolution=1920x1200
```

You then have to restart X with ctrl-alt-backspace.  I don't know of anyway to restart it on the command line but there could be a way.  When I did this for the first time, I didn't restart X, and was mystified at why the resolution wasn't changing.

Comment: Doesn't work in CentOS 7

Comment: ^^ CentOS 7 - `system-config-display: command not found`

Answer (score 3):

For my CentOS 7.2 I wanted to have 2560x1440 resolution to fit my iMac monitor
First I executed

```
$ sudo xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 32 x 32, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32768 x 32768
VNC-0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00* 
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1360x768      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00
```

Since max is 32768x32768 we can definitely do 2560x1440 resolution!
First, added the new resolution mode:

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Then added that mode to my VNC-0 screen

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode VNC-0 "2560x1440_60.00"
```

Then, Under:

Applications Menu
=>System Tools
=>Settings
=>Hardware:Dispays
=>Unknown Display (Double click)
=>Resolution
=>2560x1440

You do not even need to restart GNU Desktop  :)

Comment: I had issues figuring out what options to use for the --new-mode parameter.  So just to expand on your answer-- in order to get the Modeline options needed for the --new-mode parameter to xrandr you can use the cvt command.  Install the xorg-x11-server-Xorg package in order to use it.  Just run:  cvt X_RES Y_RES

Comment: what's a good way to make these changes permanent? I can change the resolution to e.g. 1920x1080 by manually running a script every time I log in, but that's annoying and it would be good for it to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

before sudo xrandr --newmode you must do this

gtf 2560 1440 60 -x
then use the command sudo xrandr --newmode and pick up the numbers from the gtf

or simply see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245497/how-to-manually-configure-a-monitor-in-centos7-attached-via-kvm

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very simple solution to set resolution in Hyper-v(for CentOS-8):

$ su root
$ grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
$ reboot

Where 1920x1080 is your expected resolution.

This puts following entry in grub file:

```
[root@localhost /]# cat /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cs-swap rd.lvm.lv=cs/root rd.lvm.lv=cs/swap rhgb quiet video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
[root@localhost /]#
```

This should work on all CentOS versions as it updates kernel entry for resolution.

On CentOS-9 you can easily change it through Settings->Displays->Resolution.